# how to run / test java application that contains 100s packages

Tags: eclipse, testing

Before I get bumped here, please point me to the right forum if question does not conform to post rules. I have an enterprise packaged software application I need to work on. One project that contains multiple components is my focus and that I am trying to understand; it has 100's of packages that are a far cry from the simple MVC or backend programs I have developed.

My question is how to run the code if I want to focus on one package only. I don't even know how to run this application as it contains so many parts. I have a demo installed on my system but that tells me from a user perspective what goes on. How do I test specific lasses without being able to run the application itself. Can someone please point me to resources or tutorials on how to do this>

EDIT

So I found a test project attached and some test cases. I tried to just right click and run one test class and it failed with tons of compilation errors related to about a third of the packages. Not familiar with unit testing so can someone guide me on this?

Comment: This may not be a nice experience.  Consider reading "Working Effectively With Legacy Code" (https://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion